# Make transparent background of application window

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-c++

I want to make transparent any application window not its contents using c# or vc++. For example If I opened my computer then it makes that window transparent from my application not folders.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific.  Are you asking how you can program your own application in C# as transparent?

Comment: Are you talking about making windows in your own application transparent, or windows belonging to other applications?

Comment: I want to transparent any opened window selecting from my application. For ex. my computer is opened then I can make it transaparent (its background only...) from my application NOT its folders too. Only window background transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Form properties

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
```

Comment: This will set the properties of the form in his code, but not the properties of any application on the OS.

Comment: Thanks.. it will work but As I said.. I want to do it from my application, and It will list opened windows.. like my computer, any folder etc.. and I will select it and make that window transparent from my application.

Answer (score 0):

To the Google:

http://www.intowindows.com/make-windows-7-transparent-with-system-transparency-tool/

You can do this in Windows 7 easily, no code required.  For Win 200/XP, to the Google machine once more:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4473/Making-any-application-transparent-in-Windows-2000

> bool m_bTracking;   //  will be true when the mouse is 
>                       //  being tracked HWND m_hCurrWnd;    //  Handle to the window over which 
>                       //  the mouse was last present HCURSOR m_hCursor;  //  The wand cursor
>
> //  Global definition typedef BOOL (WINAPI *lpfn) (HWND hWnd, COLORREF
>   cr, 
>                 BYTE bAlpha, DWORD dwFlags); lpfn g_pSetLayeredWindowAttributes;
>
> BOOL CWinTransDlg::OnInitDialog() {
>       ....
>       //  get the function pointer for SetLayeredWindowAttributes 
>       //  in User32.dll
>       HMODULE hUser32 = GetModuleHandle(_T("USER32.DLL"));
>       g_pSetLayeredWindowAttributes = (lpfn)GetProcAddress(hUser32,
>                  "SetLayeredWindowAttributes");
>       if (g_pSetLayeredWindowAttributes == NULL)
>           AfxMessageBox (
>               "Layering is not supported in this version of Windows",
>                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
>
> ```
> //  Load the wand cursor
> HINSTANCE hInstResource = AfxFindResourceHandle(
>      MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WAND), RT_GROUP_CURSOR);
> m_hCursor = ::LoadCursor( hInstResource, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WAND) );
> ... }
> ```
>
> void CWinTransDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
>       ...
>       SetCapture();      // make mouse move events to 
>                          // be directed to this window
>       m_hCurrWnd = NULL; // Currently no window is to be made transparent
>       m_bTracking = true;     // set the tracking flag
>       ::SetCursor(m_hCursor); // turn the mouse pointer into the wand cursor
>       ... }
>
> void CWinTransDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
>       ...
>       if (m_bTracking)
>       {
>           ...
>           //  convert mouse coordinates to screen
>           ClientToScreen(&point);
>           ...
>           //  get the window at the mouse coords
>           m_hCurrWnd = ::WindowFromPoint(point);
>           ...
>           // Show details of the window like class, caption, etc.
>           ...
>       }
>       ... }
>
> void CWinTransDlg::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
>       ...
>       //  stop tracking the mouse
>       ReleaseCapture();
>       m_bTracking = false;
>
> ```
> //  If the window under the mouse is not of this 
> //  application we toggle its
> //  layer style flag and apply the alpha as set by the slider control
> if (g_pSetLayeredWindowAttributes && m_hCurrWnd != m_hWnd)
> {
>     ::SetWindowLong(m_hCurrWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,
>                     GetWindowLong(m_hCurrWnd, 
>                     GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
>     g_pSetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_hCurrWnd, 0,
>                     (BYTE)m_slider.GetPos(), LWA_ALPHA);
>
>     ::RedrawWindow(m_hCurrWnd, NULL, NULL,
>                    RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE | 
>                    RDW_FRAME | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
> }
> ... }
> ```

Comment: You should post the snippets here as well in case the URLs ever die.